# How do you turn a Scala list into pairs?

Tags: scala

I am trying to split Scala list like `List(1,2,3,4)` into pairs `(1,2) (2,3) (3,4)`, what's a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
val xs = List(1,2,3,4)
xs zip xs.tail
  // res1: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (2,3), (3,4))
```

As the docs say, `zip`

> Returns a list formed from this list and another iterable collection
>   by combining corresponding elements in pairs. If one of the two
>   collections is longer than the other, its remaining elements are
>   ignored.

So `List('a,'b,'c,'d)` zipped with `List('x,'y,'z)` is `List(('a,'x), ('b,'y), ('c,'z))` with the final `'d` of the first one ignored.

From your example, the `tail` of `List(1,2,3,4)` is `List(2,3,4)` so you can see how these zip together in pairs.

Comment: This is short and clever, but it harder to understand I think.

Comment: This would be my first choice for conciseness and clarity. Have an upvote.

Comment: @Luigi: I upvoted this answer and much prefer it to the currently accepted one, but an explanation would be more helpful than "LOL if you think this hard to understand".

Comment: Or `xs.zip(xs.drop(1))` if you're happy to have an empty List returned when `xs` is empty - otherwise you'll get an `UnsupportedOperationException` (thrown by `tail` on an empty collection)

Answer (score 17):

To produce a list of pairs (i.e. tuples) try this

```
List(1,2,3,4,5).sliding(2).collect{case List(a,b) => (a,b)}.toList
```

Comment: Use `map` instead of `collect` — this will save an `isDefinedAt` call and throw an exception if all of a sudden your original collection is not a `List` any more, instead of silently producing an empty result. For this same reason, you should probably pattern-match `Seq(a,b)` instead of `List(a,b)`.

Answer (score 10):

```
List(1,2,3,4).sliding(2).map(x => (x.head, x.tail.head)).toList
res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (2,3), (3,4))
```

Comment: This is the answer I came up as well when I wrote it. Seems more obvious and readable than the rest imo.

Comment: @arviman This is what I came up with at the time.  I was probably trying to force the use of `sliding`. In hindsight, the accepted answer is much better.