# Alternative to List.sliding?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm trying to get more familiar with functional programming and I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to group a list into pairs of 2 and apply a function to those pairs.

```
case class Line(start: Vector, end: Vector) {
  def isLeftOf(v: Vector) = (end - start).cross(v - start) < 0
}

case class Polygon(vertices: List[Vector]) {
  def edges = (vertices.sliding(2).toList :+ List(vertices.last,vertices.head)).map(l => Line(l(0), l(1)))
  def contains(v: Vector) = {
    edges.map(_.isLeftOf(v)).forall(_ == true)
  }
}
```

I'm talking about this line

```
def edges = (vertices.sliding(2).toList :+ List(vertices.last,vertices.head)).map(l => Line(l(0), l(1)))
```

Is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 2):

```
val edges = (vertices, vertices.tail :+ vertices.head).zipped map Line
```

See also these questions:

[How do you turn a Scala list into pairs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248739/how-do-you-turn-a-scala-list-into-pairs/11249285#11249285)

[Most concise way to combine sequence elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068031/most-concise-way-to-combine-sequence-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can simplify a bit by doing this:

```
case class Polygon(vertices: List[Vector]) {
  def edges = Line(vertices.last, vertices.head) :: vertices.sliding(2).map(l => Line(l(0), l(1))).toList
  def contains(v: Vector) = edges.forall(_.isLeftOf(v))
}
```

I've done three things:

1. Pulled the last/head Line out so that it isn't part of the `map`
2. Moved `toList` to after `map` so that you map over an Iterator, saving you from constructing two Lists.
3. Simplified `contains` to simply call `forall` with the predicate.